# Is it possible to force audio through speakers while headphones are connected?

Tags: android, audio, speaker, headphones

I need to force audio through speakers because there's a headphone jack tip stuck in my connector which is most likely not coming out.
On android 8.0 I used an app called Audio Router to route the audio to speakers and it worked fine but after I upgraded to pie it doesn't work anymore.
I also tried all kinds of different apps one of which made the headphones connected indicator disappear but the audio didn't play through speakers.
I tried finding some code to do this and I've found this:

```
public void speaker(View v){
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
}
```

Nothing happens after calling the function.
I gave the app this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO"/>
```

Anybody has any idea what could possibly work ? Thanks for the answer in advance.